# Return records from todays month + 6

Tags: oracle, filtering

how can i return records sales from todays + 6 months.

Example:

Today´s month: May-2018.
Today´s month + 6: Nov-2018

So, i want a function to retrieve records from Table_Date, from November (1 to 30).

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle? Different products, different functions. In any case, retrieval isn't performed by functions, it's performed by SELECT queries. Functions are what eg adds 6 months to a date

Comment: Is in Oracle SQL

Comment: Then use the *correct* tag, post the table's schema and what you tried, what the problem is. Did you try to write a SELECT statement and couldn't find out how to write the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `TRUNC` and `ADD_MONTHS` functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   sales
WHERE  SalesDate >= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 6 )
AND    SalesDate <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 7 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have SQL server and oracle, it cant be both.

This is for SQL Server (though logic would work in ORACLE, but syntax may not)

This is to get 6 months from today
    SELECT DATEADD(MM, 6, GETDATE())

Added extra code here for more details after looking at question more:

I am using variables to do the calculations to make it easier to understand but you could do it all inline (but harder to read).

This script gets a date 6 months from now, takes that month and finds the first day of that month, and then the last day of that month so you can use those 2 dates in a where clause logic.

```
DECLARE @NewMonth AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @NewYear AS VARCHAR(10) -- in case adding months goes to next year
SELECT @NewMonth  = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MM, 6, GETDATE())),
@NewYear = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MM, 6, GETDATE()))

DECLARE @FirstOfMonth AS DATE = @NewMonth + '/1/' + @NewYear

-- for start of month check we can just hard code one in it, for end of month we cant because we dont know how many days are in it
SELECT @FirstOfMonth, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @FirstOfMonth)) AS LastDayOfMontbh
```

Comment: But if i have a columm "SalesDate" where can i put that SalesDate in the Select statement?

Comment: SalesDate is what?  Post your table schema and select statement and what you are trying to do with the dates 6 months out I provided.  Are those in your where clause?  So you want the SalesDate Between @FirstOfMonth and LastOfMonth from my code above